# How to get the full hostname of Linux server in R?

Tags: r, linux

How could I get the full host name of a linux server in R (i.e. hostname.example.com)?

I understand I can use `Sys.info()["nodename"]` to get the nodename (i.e. `hostname`) in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you allowed to use a system call? ie `system("hostname -f", intern = TRUE)` on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Yes it is working for me. But I found hostname -A is better to get external hostname, instead of internal hostname as my server has a few network addresses.

Comment: `hostname -A` requires reverse DNS to be set up.